# Windows boots to same drive after cloning

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, uefi, mbr

I am trying to transfer my windows install from one drive to another. The issue I am having is whenever I clone the drive and select the new windows boot manager, it boots to the old drive. If I unplug the old drive, I get an 0x00000e error. I believe the error is that the boot partition still points to the old drive. Is there any way to change where it points, specifically without Windows RE, I do not have a USB drive laying around?

Answer (score -1):

I've had this a few times.
I suspect at some layer, Windows prevents the boot sectors from being set to a new volume as it already has an active one.

My fix on a number of occasions was to use Macrium (free).
Create a bootable USB (for Macrium) and somewhere in there (possibly tools or utilities menu) is an option to fix boot issues.

I selected that, pointed to my volume and it has worked for me on two or three occassions.

I'd like to know a better way of doing this ... but this has definitely worked a few times for me.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).